# Asterisk SIP Header

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

Привет всем мастерам Asterisk У меня такая проблема мне нужно извлечь две переменные из SipHeader Я извлек с tcpdump и у меня есть два поля Diversion

> Diversion:sip:+4917645615686@public-vip.cisco.de>;reason=unconditional
>   Diversion:"Anonymous"sip<:Anonymous@47.23.21.9>;reason=unknow;privacy=full;counter=1

Я пытался

> `same => n,Set(diversion=${SIP_HEADER(Diversion))

но следующию строку не могу извлечь знаю
pro-sip*CLI> core show function SIP_HEADER не могу разобраца нужна помощь!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
${SIP_HEADER(Diversion,2)}
```

По крайней мере, в 11-й версии так уже работает.